# MDX to sum over months with non-empty measure value for the month

Tags: ssas, mdx

This has been stumping me and I'm not sure why it is so difficult.
I have a measure that has empty values up until a certain point in time, and then starts having values. I want to get a monthly average, but only on those months that actually have a non-empty value. I also want my time range to be fixed for the query regardless of which months have values (for example, across the whole year)

Here is one variation of MDX that I tried:

```
WITH 
MEMBER Measures.MonthsWithSales AS
    (IIF( IsEmpty(([Time].[Month].CurrentMember,[Measures].[ProductsSold])), 0,  [Measures].[MonthCount]))

MEMBER  Measures.AvgProductsSold AS
    [Measures].[ProductsSold] /Measures.MonthsWithSales

SELECT
{
[Measures].[ProductsSold], [Measures].[MonthCount],
[Measures].[MonthsWithSales], [Measures].[AvgProductsSold]
} ON 0,

[Time].[Month].Members ON 1

FROM MyCube
WHERE [Time].[Year].&[2010-01-01T00:00:00]
```

which returns something like this:

```
    ProductsSold    MonthCount  MonthsWithSales AvgProductsSold
All                     1644    12  **12**  **137**
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 (null)  1   0       (null)
2010-02-01 00:00:00.000 (null)  1   0       (null)
2010-03-01 00:00:00.000 (null)  1   0       (null)
2010-04-01 00:00:00.000 (null)  1   0       (null)
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 (null)  1   0       (null)
2010-06-01 00:00:00.000 234     1   1       234
2010-07-01 00:00:00.000 237     1   1       237
2010-08-01 00:00:00.000 236     1   1       236
2010-09-01 00:00:00.000 232     1   1       232
2010-10-01 00:00:00.000 232     1   1       232
2010-11-01 00:00:00.000 233     1   1       233
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000 240     1   1       240
```

The problem is on the ALL row.
I expect that the `MonthsWithSales` across the whole year returns 7 not 12
and that `AvgProductsSold` (per month with sales) is 234.86 not 137.

I realize that it's not doing what I want because it's using the `MonthCount` at the ALL level. But I do not know how to "sink into" the "per month dimension" to sum up the `MonthCount` only on the relevant months when it is calculating the "ALL".

Comment: Can you tell us what are the levels on the month hierarchy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assumed you have 2 levels on the month hierarchy: one with the All member and one for the months.

```
MEMBER Measures.AvgProductsSold AS 
            IIf([Time].[Month].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal = 0
                    , Avg([Time].[Month].CurrentMember.Children, [Measures].[ProductsSold])
                    , [Measures].[ProductsSold])
```

(You may have to replace `[Time].[Month].CurrentMember.Children` with `[Time].[Month].Members`)

The [Avg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146067) function computes the average on the non empty values.

Comment: This is definitely closer, except that that gives an average across the whole Time dimension, not just in the date range I have specified in my WHERE clause. (Forgive me if my use of MDX terminology is flawed, I'm trying to apply my SQL expertise into the analysis paradigm). The [Month] "hierarchy" is actually a dimension attribute and so is [Year]. I also have a true "YQMD" hierarchy on my Time dimension with Year,Quarter,Month,Date levels. Should I be using that instead?

Comment: OK, I just needed: Avg(([Time].[Year].&[2010-01-01T00:00:00],[Time].[Month].CurrentMember.Children), [Measures].[ProductsSold]) in the member definition

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query I am likely to end up using, properly using my time hierarchy:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[MonthsWithSales]
AS
COUNT
(
    FILTER
    (
        DESCENDANTS([Time].[YQMD].CurrentMember,[Time].[YQMD].[Month]),
        NOT ISEMPTY([Measures].[ProductsSold])
    )
)

MEMBER
[Measures].[AvgProductsSold]
AS
[Measures].[ProductsSold]/[Measures].[MonthsWithSales]

SELECT
{
[Measures].[ProductsSold],
[Measures].[MonthsWithSales],
[Measures].[AvgProductsSold]
} ON 0,

[Time].[Month].Members ON 1

FROM MyCube
```

The [YQMD] is a time hierarchy with Levels: 1 Year, 2 Quarter, 3 Month, 4 Date